# change position of images in an array

Tags: javascript

I am adding an image slider to my page and are trying to change the image when I click either the "left button" or "right button"

```
<div class="gallary">
  <img class="img" src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587374194137-681fd73fab43?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt='0'>
  <img class="img" src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586283294663-b82b25f4d660?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt='1'>
  <img class="img" src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502945015378-0e284ca1a5be?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt='2'>
  <img class="img" src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552236867-1caaa93299e2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt='3'>
</div>

<button class="button left"  >
  Scroll left
</button>

<button class="button right" >
  scroll right
</button>
```

And for my js file I have selected the left and right button and added a event listener to the left button

```
const btnLeft = document.querySelector(".left");
const btnRight = document.querySelector(".right");

let images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
let arr = [...images];



btnLeft.addEventListener("click", function(){
   arr.push(arr.shift());
  console.log(arr);
})
```

When I console log the array inside the function it changes order as I want to but nothing happens to my images. They stay in the same position.

Any suggestions to what I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a `copy of images`. Changing image `array position`, wont `reflect in DOM`. You need to `clear dom` and `reconstruct` it.

**Suggestion:** Instead of creating dom, use show hide on element based on position

```js
const btnLeft = document.querySelector(".left");
const btnRight = document.querySelector(".right");

let images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
let arr = [...images];
const gallary = document.querySelector(".gallary");

btnLeft.addEventListener("click", function () {
  gallary.innerHTML = "";
  arr.push(arr.shift());
  arr.forEach((dom) => {
    gallary.append(dom);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="gallary">
  <img class="img" src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587374194137-681fd73fab43?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt='0'>
  <img class="img" src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586283294663-b82b25f4d660?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt='1'>
  <img class="img" src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502945015378-0e284ca1a5be?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt='2'>
  <img class="img" src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552236867-1caaa93299e2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt='3'>
</div>

<button class="button left"  >
  Scroll left
</button>

<button class="button right" >
  scroll right
</button>
```

**Better solution:**

```js
const btnLeft = document.querySelector(".left");
const btnRight = document.querySelector(".right");

let images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
let activeIndex = 0;
toggleImage(activeIndex);
btnLeft.addEventListener("click", function () {
  activeIndex -= 1;
  if (activeIndex < 0) {
    activeIndex = images.length-1;
  }
  toggleImage(activeIndex);
});
btnRight.addEventListener("click", function () {
  activeIndex += 1;
  if (activeIndex >= images.length) {
    activeIndex = 0;
  }
  toggleImage(activeIndex);
});
function toggleImage(index) {
  images.forEach((img) => {
    img.classList.remove("active");
    img.classList.add("hide");
  });
  images[index].classList.remove("hide");
  images[index].classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
.active {
      border: 1px solid;
      display: block;
    }
    .gallary .hide {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="gallary">
    <img class="img" src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587374194137-681fd73fab43?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt='0'>
    <img class="img" src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586283294663-b82b25f4d660?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt='1'>
    <img class="img" src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502945015378-0e284ca1a5be?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt='2'>
    <img class="img" src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552236867-1caaa93299e2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt='3'>
  </div>
  
  <button class="button left"  >
    Scroll left
  </button>
  
  <button class="button right" >
    scroll right
  </button>
```